# Angular 6, Externally update variables from data in form fields filled by javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm essentially trying to add data to a website from a desktop database/CRM tool, where no API exists to the website.
I've found I can load up the webpage, login and use Javascript to fill the form with data from the CRM.

I can see the form fields are correct with my values. However the Angular 6 variables don't update unless I actually physically type in the form fields. So I get 'required field' warnings.

Is the there a way to force Angular to pick up the values in the form fields?

Comment: Could you please post the code and proper use case?

Comment: document.getElementById('myField').value = 'myValue'

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which events are causing the Angular model to update

```
document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea').forEach(obj => { obj.keyup(); });
```

Try blur, keyup, change. Angular will be listening to some DOM event handler. Refine the query in the query selector to be a bit more targeted at your inputs and not the whole page.

How did you fill in the field? If you did something like

```
document.getElementById('someId').value = 'New Value';
```

Then try calling the DOM events on the element you set.

Comment: Yep, that's how I'm setting the values. I already tried keyup() and change() immediately after setting each field with no effect, I'll try blur. And I'll try your blanket solution to see if that gets it.

Comment: Ok. I couldn't trigger the change events with your code. keyup is not a function.
But I can use jquery

$('#myFirstField').val("myValue");
$('#myFirstField').blur();      //also tried change(), keydown(), keyup()

Same effect - The validation code can't see the value. So assume the underlying variables are not being set until physical interaction happens

Comment: You can achieve it by  write the code in ngAfterViewInit life cycle  of angular.

Comment: I don't have access to the pre complied code of the site. I'm trying to integrate my data with an external site.

Comment: In the old days I would have tried something like $scope.$apply(). Effectively I'm looking for a way to this from the browser debug console.

Comment: i dont think this is possible, as the underlying model object doesn't get set.